# Another Capitalization question

Tags: php, capitalization

here is what I am trying to do.  I have titles to pages. I'm trying to capitalize the last letter of the first word in each string

Examples:

hellO

hellO how are you

I can get it to work with one word but I cant figure out how to do it if there is more than one word.  Any help would be great!!

Thanks so much!

Comment: why oh why, it's normal grammar.

Comment: Try showing us the code you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

    $title                  = "Hello World";
    list($firstword, $rest) = explode(" ", $title, 2);
    $firstword              = strrev(ucfirst(strrev($firstword)));
    $title                  = $firstword . " " . $rest;

    print $title;
```

If you want to read more on any function see [explode](http://in.php.net/explode), [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php), [list](http://php.net/list), [ucfirst](http://php.net/ucfirst)

Comment: They are fast to get reputation, Kathy.

Comment: ofcourse we are. But we do have the good intention to help others too. The reputation is for helping others, not being fast. If you reply fast with wrong answer you will lose your reputation, not gain. So it is information sharing and helping first and reputation second. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the way how this works with 1 word, you only need to get the first word and then put your algorithm.

1. Try `preg_replace_callback` with `"/^(\w+)/"`
2. Replace the last char within the callback method.

preg_replace_callback: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

UPDATE - working code:

```
$string = "This is a test";
$string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/^(\w+)/',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return yourUCLastAlgorithm($matches[0]);'
        ),
        $string
    );
echo $string;
```

UPDATE2 - using preg_replace with e modifier:

```
$string = "This is a test";
$string = preg_replace(
        '/^(\w+)/e',
        'yourUCLastAlgorithm("$1")',
        $string
    );
echo $string;
```

Comment: Don't you think regular expressions with lamda functions are a bit overkill here, when you can do this with generic functions?

Comment: Have another idea: using preg_replace with e modifier.

Comment: Generally I always try to use regexps over custom splitting solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^([ ]+)?([^ ]*)([a-z])?(.*)?$/i', "$1.$2.strtoupper($3).$4", $string);
```

Comment: Why to use regular expression if not needed? Its too expensive

Comment: Because that was the first thought ^^'

Comment: `This is a test` => `.This.strtoupper(). is a test` Please check before posting.